# How to integrate virtualbox (NFV infrastructure) with open source MANO (OSM) and openstack virtual infrastructure manager (VIM)

Tags: virtualbox, open-source, openstack, virtualization

I want to emulate the NFV framework for one of my projects and I have proprietary software that can only be deployed as a virtual machine in VirtualBox. From the research, I found that VirtualBox uses Type-2 hypervisor and ETSI NFV Standards do not mandate a specific hypervisor. Now, I have my network function running as a VNF. This architecture can be mapped to NFV infrastructure functional block of the NFV, as it has VNFs, Virtual Hardware, Type-2 Hypervisor, and Physical Hardware.

1. Is it safe to assume that my implementation is an emulation of the NFV framework because I do not really need VIM and MANO for this project?

I also researched that I can use  [OpenStack](https://www.openstack.org/) as a VIM and [OSM](https://osm.etsi.org/) as the MANO. My proprietary software does not have an image and can't be instantiated through VIM. The only way is deploying through VirtualBox. If my first assumption is wrong, is there a way to integrate VirtualBox (NFV infrastructure) with OpenStack (VIM) and OSM (MANO).